# Creating a program where a sentence is turned all caps and all lowercase in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program in C++ where it will turn whatever sentence you input into

-all caps

-all lowercase

-capitalized letters will be switched with lowercase & vice versa

I've written everything up correctly so far, the only part I can't figure out is how to get it to give me back the three individual responses. If I only have one function within the while loop it works fine, but not with all three & I don't know how to get  around that. Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void allCaps(char ch);
void allLows(char ch);
void mixed(char ch);
char ch;

int main()
{

  printf("Enter Sentence:\n");

  while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
  {

    allCaps(ch);
    printf("%c",ch,"\n");
    allLows(ch);
    printf("%c",ch,"\n");
    mixed(ch);
    printf("%c",ch,"\n");


  }

  return ch;
}
void allCaps(char ch)
{
  if(ch >= 'a' && ch <='z')
     ::ch=ch-32;

}
void allLows(char ch)
{
  if(ch>='A'&&ch<='Z')
     ::ch=ch+32;
}

void mixed(char ch)
{
  if(ch >= 'a' && ch <='z')
     ::ch=ch-32;
  else if(ch>='A'&&ch<='Z')
     ::ch=ch+32;
}
```

Comment: Look up `toupper` and `tolower`

Comment: As well as [`isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper) and [`islower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/islower).

Comment: Char is single character you should use string or array of chars

Comment: Sidenode in addition to all other comments: having this _global_ variable `ch` is a terrible thing.

Comment: Also note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`. And that the input might not end with a newline.

Comment: And if you're really programming in C++ (the only C++-specific thing you use is the scope operator to modify the global variable `ch`) then why not use actual C++ functionality like input or output streams and references? Perhaps you should take a few steps back and [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is outputting each letter 3 times in a row as you read it.

Instead of doing this, you could define for example three strings like this:                            `std::string s1="",s2="",s3="";` 
and then you can do

```
s1+=allCaps(ch);s2+=allLows(ch);s3+= mixed(ch);
```

inside your while loop and at the end you simply output `s1`,`s2` and `s3`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you could use io-streams, `tolower` and `toupper`, references and other [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) specific functionalities your main problem is the global variable `ch`.

Consider what happens if you input the char `'A'`. `allCaps()` will get the upper case 'A' as an input, convert it into a (still) upper case 'A' and store the result in the global variable `ch`. This `ch` (now (or still) containing `'A'`) will now be passed to `allLows()` which again will now convert the upper case `'A'` into an lower case `'a'` and store the result again in your global `ch`. Here comes the interesting part. Remember you initially entered an upper case `'A'` so `mixed()` should produce a lower case letter right? But since `allLows()` already converted your input to an lower case letter, `mixed()` will now produce a upper letter again.

You can fix this by not declaring `ch` globally and make your functions return the result instead. e.g. see the new `allCaps()`

```
char allCaps(char ch) 
{
  if(ch >= 'a' && ch <='z')
    return ch - 32;
  return ch;
}
```

And use it like so

```
int main()
{
  printf("Enter Sentence:\n");

  char ch; // <-- local declaration
  while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    printf("%c\n", allCaps(ch)); <-- all get the same (not modified) input
    printf("%c\n", allLows(ch));
    printf("%c\n", mixed(ch));
  }
}
```

However this will still not do exactly what you want. Instead of reading a single character read a whole `std::string` for example using [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and then loop over each character and convert it using `tolower` and `toupper`